# Addin Id to an array objects in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactJs app that fetches records from API, the problem is that the records from the API don't have an ID.
I want to add an Id to each one of the records after adding them to the state.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to give us more details than that. What kind of ID? What have you tried? (And possibly why you need an ID)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of open-source npm packages for generating unique IDs. You can use [uuid npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) or [chance npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chance).

This might help: [Check this](https://chancejs.com/basics/natural.html).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{name: 'abc'},{name: 'xyz'},{name: 'abdc'},{name: 'abc1'}]

const result = data.map((dt,index) => {
      return {...dt,id:index}
})

console.log(result)
```

I think you have to use like this

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching the results, iterate over them and add some id ( also can be index in this case. )

```
const x = [{ "name": "A" }, { "name": "B" }]
```

```
const list = x.map((item, index) => { ...item, id: index })
```